# Canvas stroke text for every object in array but draw just one image

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to draw small image on canvas and some text for every person which I have in array.
I  am doing like this

```
function drawPersonsOnCanvas(canvas, persons) {
    var workIcon = '../images/work.png';
    var partyIcon = '../images/party.png';

    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var width = canvas.width;
    var height = canvas.height;
// randomizePositions just put every object of array on random position inside canvas
    persons = randomizePositions(persons, width, height);
    for (var i in persons) {
        var person= persons[i];

        person['image'] = new Image();
        person['image'].src = (person['type'] === 'work') ? workIcon: partyIcon;
        person['image'].onload = function() {
            context.drawImage(person['image'], person['x'], person['y']);
        };
        context.strokeText('person ' + person['status'], person['x'], person['y']);
    }
}
```

and I always get all texts on map on good positions and just one image and x and y are different for all ( I have 5 persons in array, I tried and without onload but it doesn't work). Does anyone know what to change so I get one picture for every person?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Is only one image displayed although there should be five, or do you get five times the same image although you would expect different images? A screenshot would help.

Comment: @Philipp I need five images but it draws only one. Text is drawn five times on good locations and there also should be one image with text, but four texts are missing image and only one has image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time each `onload` is executed, your `person` variable has already been reassigned to the next element in persons.

So you need to **create a new person variable inside `onload`.**

To do this, add an index to your person[‘image’] that points to the correct person.

```
    …
    person['image'].index=i;
    person['image'].src = (person['type'] === 'work') ? workIcon: partyIcon;
    …
```

Then inside onload you can recreate the correct person:

```
        var person=persons[this.index];
```

So your reworked code looks like this...and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/xms9B/

```
function drawPersonsOnCanvas(canvas, persons) {

    var workIcon = '../images/work.png';
    var partyIcon = //'../images/party.png';

    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var width = canvas.width;
    var height = canvas.height;
// randomizePositions just put every object of array on random position inside canvas
    persons = randomizePositions(persons, width, height);
    for (var i in persons) {
        var person= persons[i];
        person['image'] = new Image();
        person['image'].onload = function() {
            var person=persons[this.index];
            context.drawImage(person['image'], person['x'], person['y']);
            context.strokeText('person ' + person['status'], person['x'], person['y']);
        };
        person['image'].index=i;
        person['image'].src = (person['type'] === 'work') ? workIcon: partyIcon;
    }
}
```